# popup window similar to sketchpad

Tags: jquery, html, popupwindow

I want to know how to get the popup window similar to this one [Sketchpad](http://mugtug.com/sketchpad/)

Please help me how can I do? I want to have similar functionalities..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help: http://www.jquerylabs.com/sketchpad.html

Comment: Thanks for the info..I looked in..Its too much code in it..really couldn't get hold of the concept..

Comment: Any suggested links on creating a popup window when a button is clicked??

Comment: I think you could do with a different question for that, but if it helps, I really like the [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) plugin for jQuery. If you click on the _Iframe (75% width and height)_ link to see it pop up a window. Opening on a button click, just hook onto an item and listen for a `.click()`.